# How can i select a tag and copy every child expect something and give a new parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I need select a tag with his all child tag but i need delete a sepcial tag what can be anywhere in the "main" tag. The "main" tag in my example is the Deeper2 and i need delete all "ShouldDelete" tag with his value (So delete that row). After i can clear this selected tag, i need put it in a new "border". My xml like this:

```
<Edge>
    <Deeper>
        <Deeper2>
            <Something>..</Something>
            <Something2>..</Something2>
            <Something3>..</Something3>
            <Something4>..</Something4>
            <Something5>
                <Something6>..</Something6>
                <Something7>..</Something7>
                <ShouldDelet>..</ShouldDelet>
            </Something5>
            <Something8>..</Something8>
            <Something9>..</Something9>
            <Something10>
                <Something6>..</Something6>
                <ShouldDelet>..</ShouldDelet>
            </Something10>
            <ShouldDelet>..</ShouldDelet>
        </Deeper2>
    </Deeper>
</Edge>
```

And i need this:

```
<Deeper2>
    <Something>..</Something>
    <Something2>..</Something2>
    <Something3>..</Something3>
    <Something4>..</Something4>
    <Something5>
        <Something6>..</Something6>
        <Something7>..</Something7>
    </Something5>
    <Something8>..</Something8>
    <Something9>..</Something9>
    <Something10>
        <Something6>..</Something6>
    </Something10>
</Deeper2>
```

After all a need put it in a new "border" like this:

```
<MyNewTag>
    <MyNewTag2>
        <Deeper2>
            <Something>..</Something>
            <Something2>..</Something2>
            <Something3>..</Something3>
            <Something4>..</Something4>
            <Something5>
                <Something6>..</Something6>
                <Something7>..</Something7>
            </Something5>
            <Something8>..</Something8>
            <Something9>..</Something9>
            <Something10>
                <Something6>..</Something6>
            </Something10>
        </Deeper2>
    </MyNewTag2>
</MyNewTag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an identity template (basically an exact copy of your input) and override templates. The following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Edge">
        <MyNewTag>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </MyNewTag>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Deeper">
        <MyNewTag2>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </MyNewTag2>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- an empty match deletes the node -->
    <xsl:template match="ShouldDelet"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to you input XML, produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyNewTag>
   <MyNewTag2>
      <Deeper2>
         <Something>..</Something>
         <Something2>..</Something2>
         <Something3>..</Something3>
         <Something4>..</Something4>
         <Something5>
            <Something6>..</Something6>
            <Something7>..</Something7>
         </Something5>
         <Something8>..</Something8>
         <Something9>..</Something9>
         <Something10>
            <Something6>..</Something6>
         </Something10>
      </Deeper2>
   </MyNewTag2>
</MyNewTag>
```

Comment: And when the old "border" not equal with the new "border"? So when i need delete the old border what is 2 tag and i need a 4 new tag border?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand completely. Would you like to modify your question and present your desired output?

Comment: Sorry for my horrible english. So i need a tag and it depth is 4 tag. I need my tag and it inside and put it in a new tagtree what depth is 7 tag. So can i manualy put in the code this tagtree and put my old tag (where deleted the ShouldDelete tag) it inside?

Comment: I'm very sorry I really can't understand. Maybe you can show an example instead.